# Node app eating memory incrementally over time

Tags: node.js, express, memory-leaks, v8, digital-ocean

I've just launched two Express servers on DigitalOcean along with an instance of mongodb. I'm using PM2 to keep both of them running.

When I use htop to see the memory usage, the total usage is usually around 220-235mb (out of a total 488mb). The only thing I can see changing is the blue bars which I assume is buffer memory, the actual green memory in usage seems to always be around same.

I look on DO's graph however and over the past 24 hours the memory graph has been climbing upwards slowly, say 0.5% of the total per hour, sometimes it drops but overall it's on the up, at the moment it has been hovering around 60-65% of the total memory for a few hours.

There has been almost no traffic on these node web servers yet the memory keeps increasing slowly. So my question is could this be a memory leak within one of my servers or is it the nature of the v8 engine to incrementally expand its memory?

Comment: I know this is an old post, but didi you ever find a true memory leak in your app?  or was PM2 a part of the issue?  I'm using PM2 to manage a group of forked apps (running a single node app codebase), and I can see the memory increasing ever so slowly... there appears to be some general 'clean up' but overall it increases steadily.  I am using PM2 memory threshold to auto / gracefully restart  if it ever were to go really really high.  I may just gather more facts and let it run for a month to see how high it gets though.

Comment: @tamak - A bit late with my reply but it went up everyday and then dropped again. It consistently did this so I figured it was just garbage collection taking place. It never crashed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are considering memory-leak, then why don't you check your theory by writing 2-3 heapdumps with 2-3 hours difference in time. Then you can answer surely on your question.

You may use [this module](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-heapdump) to write heapdumps on disk and then simply compare it using Chrome Developer Tools. Moreover you will see what's exactly placed inside the heap.

FYI: [snapshots comparison from official documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/heap-profiling#views_comparison)